# Changing amount of "classes" in layer properties using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS and Im having trouble choosing how many classes I want. In this case I have a map of a country and its countys, with the population devided into 21 classes. I want to change this to maybe 4 classes but I do not know how to do so.

Does anyone know how to?

[image]

Comment: Switch to `Graduated` styling (top-most dropdown selection)

Comment: @geozelot, why you did not put as an answer? :)

Comment: @Taras ,) because **a)** there was no time to write a comprehensive answer, and **b)** I like the idea of providing incentive to self-research and possible solutions, and a resulting self-answer.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I think will use them in future

Answer (score 2):

To change the classification, you can use **Graduated** classification and choose which column it uses for classifying. In your case **bef_tot__1**. Choose the number of classes. It should give you the result you want.

[image]